# Xamarin C#: can't send List<int> through an intent

Tags: java, c#, android, android-intent, xamarin

I've got a problem that I'm really scratching my head over. I just started trying to make an android app with Xamarin in Visual Studio, and I'm trying to pass a `List<int>` to a new activity, with an Intent. Here's my `MainActivity.cs` code.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Content;

namespace adrd_count {
    [Activity(Label = "adrd_count", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : ListActivity {

        static readonly List<int> savedCounters = new List<int>();


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            savedCounters.Add(3);
            savedCounters.Add(2342);
            savedCounters.Add(-122211);
            savedCounters.Add(9);
            savedCounters.Add(1941);

            ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<int>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, savedCounters);



        }

        protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            var t = savedCounters[position];
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Counter));
            intent.PutIntegerArrayListExtra("saved_counter", savedCounters);

            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Now what's stumping me is that this line:

`intent.PutIntegerArrayListExtra("saved_counter", savedCounters);`

Is giving me this error:

`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Java.Lang.Integer>'`

Because, as far as I know, I'm coding in C#... not Java. There's nothing like `Integer` in C# as far as I know, and an error that transcends the language barrier makes me think I'm doing something horribly wrong. Am I just reading it incorrectly? Have I been programming in Java the whole time? What do I do?

Comment: Try savedCounters.ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic C# `List<T>` using `Java.Lang.Integer` and that can be assigned to `Intent` via `PutIntegerArrayListExtra`:

```
var intList = new List<Integer>() { (Integer)0, (Integer)1 };
~~~~
intent.PutIntegerArrayListExtra("saved_counter", intList);
```

When constructing an `Intent`, you are interacting with a Java-based object via a C# object and its wrappers and thus have two "peer" objects that are on two VMs, the Art/Dalvik and Mono. So, yes, Java rules apply to that object but there are conversions builtin....

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of C# [Json.Net](https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net) to pass List or any objects as intent.

Any object can be Serialised into a string (json string) using JSON.Net

```
string listAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
intent.PutExtra ("saved_counter", listAsString);
```

Then you can convert it back into your List<> as follows:

```
string listAsString = Intent.GetStringExtra ("saved_counter");
List<Integer> savedCounter JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Integer>> (listAsString);
```